# Infinite Triple Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math

The following triple sum appeared in a recent mathematical competition at a local university:

$$\sum_{j,k,l\geq0} \frac{1}{3^l\left(3^{j+k}+3^{k+l}+3^{l+j}\right)}$$

I know the answer is $\frac{9}{8}$, but I have no clue how to proceed with the problem.

As an addendum, what is the general closed form of the sum when $3$ is replaced with a positive integer other than $1$?

Comment: What is known about a way in which $(j,k,l)$ go through $\mathbb {N_0}^3$? Or that is not important? What path do they follow? Or they just go through all possible triples?

Comment: they just go through all possible triples

Comment: Can you write a program that will evaluate that sum for, for example, all triples from $(0,0,0)$ to, let`s say $(30,30,30)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$S=\sum_{i,j,k \geq 0} \frac{1}{3^i(3^{i+j}+3^{i+k}+3^{j+k})}$$

Note that $$\frac{1}{3^i}+\frac{1}{3^j}+\frac{1}{3^k} = \frac{3^{i+j}+3^{i+k}+3^{j+k}}{3^{i+j+k}}$$

Hence $$3S=\sum_{i,j,k \geq 0} \frac{1}{3^{i+j+k}} = (\frac{3}{2})^3$$
therefore $S=9/8$.

Comment: Very nice, indeed.

Comment: The identity gives a denominator that is the sum of three fractions, a far cry from the final sum. What gives?