# Can someone check something for me in the computational sense?

Tags: sequences-and-series, experimental-mathematics, programming

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485220/infinite-triple-sum) it is presented the sum which  appeared in a recent mathematical competition at a local university: $$\sum_{j,k,l\geq0} \frac{1}{3^l\left(3^{j+k}+3^{k+l}+3^{l+j}\right)}$$ and it is said that the answer is $9/8$.

There also the answer is given which proves that the sum is $9/8$ but I am somehow disagreed with that approach of proving that the sum is $9/8$, and that disagreement is based on some pencil-and-paper calculations of mine that suggest me that this sum is not equal to $9/8$, in hope that those calculations are right.

So, I am not asking too much, only that someone calculates this sum for some cube constrained by $(0\leq j\leq m)$ and $(0\leq k\leq m)$ and $(0\leq l\leq m)$, where she/he can take that $m$ to be small enough in a sense that computer does not take much time to calculate the sum, but again, if my approach is right, then $9/8$ should be exceeded at some point.

I do not have any programming languages on a computer so I cannot do this task without your help.

Comment: If experimental or computing mathematics is one of your interests you should use Linux OS which always comes with Python language, in which one can  write short code for this type of purposes quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
// gcc threesum.c -o threesum.exe -std=c99 -Wall -O3

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  long double sum = 0;

  for (int total = 30; total >= 0; total--)
  for (int j = 0; j <= total; j++)
  for (int k = 0; k <= total - j; k++) {
    int l = total - j - k;

    long double t = 3.0;
    long double denom = pow(t, l)*( pow(t, j + k) + pow(t, k + l) + pow(t, l + j) );
    long double addend = 1.0 / denom;

    sum += addend;
  }

  printf("%f\n", (double)sum);
}


1.125000
```

Comment: Can you explain to me that computational stuff and code? What are the bounds for your variables?

Comment: It checks all $(j, k, l)$ such that $0 \le j + k + l \le 10$.  Beyond that you are only adding values around $3^{-30}$, so I think it is close enough.

Comment: Can you push that calculation up to $m=30$ and tell me what happens?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen There you go.  I even changed it to long double to record more decimal places and changed it to add up the smaller values first so there won't be rounding errors.  I suggest writing a new post showing your work for solving the problem, you'd probably get your issue pointed out in under 5 minutes.

Comment: But now your result is exactly $9/8$, and not all terms are summed because there is an infinite number of them and you checked only the small cube that I wanted to be checked, right? Haha, this is awesome.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Just because the double is given as $1.125000$ doesn't mean it's exactly $9/8$; it's very close, but slightly below. The roundoff from the terms of order $3^{-90}$ is completely negligible. The series *does* sum to $9/8$.

Comment: @user296602 I still doubt, maybe someone will push it up to, for example $m=50$ or $m=100$, and then it will exceed, but again, it could be that my calculations are not right, I can accept that also.

Comment: I really thank you both for discussing this with me.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen I ran it in python up to $m = 200$, and got $1.1249999999999523$ due to a slight numerical roundoff error. Seriously, the terms that you're talking about are absolutely minuscule, and unless you have some compelling reason for thinking that the posted answer is wrong, this isn't a good use of CPU cycles.

Comment: @user296602 Both of you seem to be right, in my calculations I included first term $(0,0,0)$ three times, and that term is the biggest one, so that probably gave me the result bigger than the one given in an answer.

Comment: I just now saw that.

Comment: Just curiosity, how did they compute the sum exactly?

Comment: @vonbrand https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2485315/97045

Comment: you are right. That answer is completely off-track.